# What is the Index - Normal - FullText - Unique

Tags: php, mysql

Same the title : What is the Index - Normal - FullText - Unique ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A normal index is used to speed up operation by only containing a slice or hash of the row's data.

A fulltext index indicates to the database's fulltext search (FTS) engine that it should archive the data within the given fields for quicker searching through large volumes of text.

A unique index is similar to a normal index, but also imposes upon the database that the specific combination of fields within the index will be unique across the entire table.

Comment: It's just... a piece, a chunk, a portion.